# Hibernate could not initialize proxy

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm getting the following exception..

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/assessment] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at org.assessme.com.entity.User_$$_javassist_0.getFirstName(User_$$_javassist_0.java)
    at org.assessme.com.UserManagementController.data(UserManagementController.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The problem I'm pretty sure of is in my DAO...

```
public class UserDAO {

    public User getById(Long id) {
        HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User user = (User) session.load(User.class, id);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return user;
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to handle the transactions?  Should I do buildSessionFactory every time I want to return an object?  Is it better to only do it once?

Comment: you should put session creation outside the method, even better if you could autowire session to the userDAO.

Comment: What method of [transaction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) are you using? Do you have [OpenSessionInViewFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) configured in `web.xml`?

Comment: Do you have any examples I could follow regarding the autowiring?  Thank you for your advice :)

Comment: also - just to add, I already have the spring libs as I'm using it for SpringMVC, but I've not used any of the autowiring stuff yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session.beginTransaction()` returns the Transaction object, you should call the commit into that instance. You are handling two separate transactions in each `session.getTransaction()`.
Also make sure you close the session (`session.close()`) in any place.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/es-ES/html/example-weblog.html

Answer (score 1):

Try

> HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().beginSession();

instead of ...getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

In your case, if no session has been previously created, you're not retrieving an active session.